# What is the codenameone calendar component lifecycle?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, codenameone

I am trying to customise a Calendar component in CodeNameOne.

However its not clear about the Lifecycle events or methods of a component! Is there a document somewhere or any guidelines will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Should style CalendarDay in the designer to have the look you want: Font, padding etc.

The CalendarTitle UIID can be styled with blue to represent the colors.

To do this double click the theme.res and select the "Theme", press "Add" and type in either CalendarDay or CalendarTitle. Proceed to derive or override as necessary to produce the desired look. See this for more information: https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---create-a-simple-theme.html

To localize the titles define your own localization bundle as explained here: https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---localizetranslate-my-application-apply-i18nl10n-internationalizationlocalization-to-my-app.html

Comment: Thanks @GRV_Droid for the response. Do you know the lifecycle events or methods for CodeNameOne custom component writing. Seems like there is no documentation on that as to how to bind methods to a particular life cycle event.

Answer (score 1):

Components live from the time that they are instantiated (e.g. `Button myBtn = new Button("Click me")`), to when they are garbage collected.  Garbage collection occurs when there are no longer any references to the component.

The main lifecycle to be concerned about is when the component is added or removed from a `Form`.

The component's [`initComponent()`](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Component.html#initComponent--) method is called when the component is added to a form.  It's [`deinitialize()`](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Component.html#deinitialize--) method is called when it is removed from the form.

You can override these methods in your custom Component if you want to be informed of these events.

Comment: Thanks @steve for the response.
Apart from ` initComponent()` and `deinitialize()` are there any other lifecycle methods!

Suppose I want to initialise some default values in the `constructor` and at some point I want to reset them to default. Just thinking is there a way where a lifecycle method is being called at a regular interval such as `data change` or `render again`

Thanks

Comment: Check out the [Component javadoc page](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Component.html) to see all of the methods.  There are several places to plug in.  E.g. The `paint()` method is called to draw the component, `calcPreferredSize()` is called to get the preferred size of the component when laying out in a container.   Pay attention to methods marked `protected` as these are generally the ones intended to override to hook into workflows.  Also, if you haven't already, read the [basics section of the developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/basics.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot @steve